# Vue installing error and when install package

Tags: vue.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6K9Mf.png)

and the same thing when I try to install firebase or any other package

Answer (score 1):

I feel it installed the vuejs. can you type vue --version which will tell the version.

Comment: Can you please share your errors whih you got while installing firebase or any other packages  ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no errors, just depricated packages, which you cand update in future. You need to learn how to post a question, defenetly not like that.

Comment: yes, there is no problem here but I can't install any package.

Comment: I said I cant use any package for example firebase don't work and always tell me to install it